# Sequelize wherein and andWhere

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have an array of ids.
I need to get the rows among this set whose name equals 'red'

Something like :
`whereIn('id',[1,2,3]) andWhere (name='red')`
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Table_Name.findAll({
      where: {
        id: {$in: [1, 2, 3]},
        name: 'red'
      }
    })
```

Comment: You have made the same mistake as me - find instead of findAll. Please edit and i'l accept the answer.

Comment: oh! yes you are right ... findAll is correct. I have updated

Answer (score -1):

Use in mysql:

```
select *from table_name where id in (your_array) and name = 'red';
```

You can pass the array using your js code.